# Origin of *dhvor-

Tags: etymology, comparative-linguistics, proto-indo-european

Formerly as I remember I saw somewhere *dhvor- (door, gate, yard, court) connected with the root *vert- (turn) in PIE. This is quite realistic and can be supported with similar Russian words *створка* (*stvorka*) meaning leaf of a door or a gate or a small door, and *затвор* (*zatvor*) (gate, lock), both originating from PIE *vert-.

But Starostin links *dhvor- to Eurasiatic *durV (Kartvelian: *dur-, Dravidian: *tūr-) meaning "hole". This is quite strange given the difference in meaning and also that *durV strikingly resembles Russian *дыра* (*dyra*) also meaning "hole". Vasmer links Russian *дыра* with Lithuanian duríù, dùriau, dùrti (stab, make hole) but further etymology is uncertain. It is quite natural to suggest that this word is connected to Eurasiatic *durV instead of idea that *durV is connected to *dhvor-.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: The question is whether *dhvor- is really connected to *durV

Comment: If certain questions get closed for "being about a particular language", then certainly questions should be closed for "being about a particular hypothetical form in a reconstructed language". That said: I vote that we don't close _either_.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Yes**, it seems that BSL `*dhvor` < PIE `*dhuor-` / `*dhur-` < Skt. `dAra` / `dvAra`.

   > I saw somewhere *dhvor- (door, gate, yard, court) connected with the root *vert-
2. **No**, it does not seem correct.

De Vaan, 2008 (p.233) lists PIE `*dhuor-` and `*dhur-` as synonyms.
Also, Whitney, 1879 (#399) explained on vowel-to-consonant transition and suggested examples `dvāra` and `dura`.

In Sanskrit, दार `[dAra]` and द्वार `[dvAra]` are [mostly synonyms](http://www.live4india.com/forum/printthread.php?tid=410). They both mean entrance, and they are [often interchangeable](http://navshakti.co.in/2012/02/03/%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE/) in sacral texts.

On the other hand, there's no evidence that द्वार `[dvAra]` can be related to वृत्र `[vRtra]` (to rotate).

P.S. In Russian, there are many words derived from `[vRtra]`, including "вертеть" `[vʲer'tʲetʲ]` (to rotate, to turn) and "ворота" `[vɐr'otɐ]` (gate). The least has an ancient form of "врата" `[vrɐt'a]`.

Comment: What indicates that Sanskrit "dara" is not just a contraction of "dvara" happened inside Sanskrit? Why do you connect it to Eurasiatic *dura?

Comment: @Anixx: De Vaan, 2008 (p.233) lists PIE `*dhuor-` and `*dhur-` as synonyms. Also, Whitney, 1879 (#399) explained on vowel-to-consonant transition and suggested examples `dvāra` and `dura`.

Comment: Also, there was a bad typo in the 1st answer, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: *dhuor- and *dhur- are not synonyms; they are different ablaut grades of the same root.

Comment: Your initial sentence does not make sense. Nothing in PIE can descend from Sanskrit. By definition, Sanskrit is a descendant of PIE.